# CPP printf giving no output on VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I have a simple CPP code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main () {
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
printf("\nEnter two numbers:\n");
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

c = a+b;
printf("\nc = %d", c);
return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that the first `printf` statement is getting printed but the second one is not. The code is exiting without printing anything. However when I debug using breakpoints, the value of `c` is getting stored in it.

Comment: Does the console windows showing the printed message getting closed automatically?

Comment: It prints the statement.

Comment: Try to remove the space between the 2 %ds in your scanf. Maybe it will work.

Comment: Try setting your breakpoint at the line `return 0;`

Comment: @armanali it didn't help!@

Comment: Select *Debug* -> *Start Without Debugging* (Ctrl+F5) from the Visual Studio IDE. This will make sure the console window stays open so that you can read the output.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a wild guess and say you run this from your IDE.

It does print the output. But the program then ends. And it ends so fast, you cannot see the output. If you want your program to wait for you to see it, you will need to find a way to make it wait. For example with another `scanf` line.

As there is no standard, environment agnostic way to say "*Press any key to continue*", have a look [here](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1042856625&id=1043284385) for some alternatives.

Comment: I have tried using fflush(stdout) to hold the output but it didn't help. I get a statement on the output window of VS2012 that the code exited.

Comment: @Sid well, that probably *did* flush the output. But the application does not wait for you to read it. It prints it and a split second later, it closes the application. You will need a way for the window to stay open, until you press a key for example, so you have time to read it.

Comment: Not such a wild guess, it's probably the #1 question about C/C++ on the Internet. =)

Comment: #3 after "why does this segfault  <code with buffer overflow or unintialized pointer>", and "how do I a 2-D array"

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` to the end of the last `printf`. It is implementation-defined whether the last line of output to `stdout` actually gets flushed , if it doesn't end in a newline.

Comment: adding this didn't make any difference. still no output

Answer (score -1):

When you use

> scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

then you should give 2 inputs separated by space or enter

> scanf("%d,%d", &a, &b);

then you should give 2 input separated by comma(,).

and at last use

> printf("Press any key to continue.."); getche(); instead of return;